# How to fix GCloud App Engine ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR?

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform

I'm hoping there is a simple solution that I keep overlooking. I created an app on Google Cloud App Engine in Python, with some REST APIs. Whenever I try to use the API I get an ssl error.

When using `HTTPClient` I get a handshake error, and when I go in the browser I get `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`. Interestingly, if I first use HTTP, and then HTTPS it starts working perfectly, for a short while at least.

This is the first I've used Google Cloud. From what I read in the documentation, App Engine takes care of all of the HTTPS stuff, including certificates. Is there something I'm missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
Comcast is actually blocking all connections to my web service. I can access it perfectly over a VPN. Does anyone know how I can fix things to get through comcast? Otherwise my web service is useless whenever Comcast is involved.

Comment: Please share with us more details. What are the full error messages? Your use case, which App Engine environment are you choosing(Standard/Flex)? Did you follow any documentation? Did you follow any documentation to set SSL for your domain?

Comment: I am using the standard environment, with F1 instance class (tried with F2 instance class). I read though a lot of documentation, which only mentioned setting up certificates for custom domains. I am only using the supplied appspot.com domain right now, no custom domain. When it does work, by doing http request before https, a valid certificate is received. The browser only indicates the ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, and I cannot find any other details. In the app with httpclient I get SSL handshake error 100000f7 Version Incorrect. Though I have checked and TLS versions 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 available

Comment: When watching with wireshark, I see a valid Client Hello being sent, but no Server Hello response. As said before I can use http first and then https and all works. At that point wireshark shows a Server Hello response being received. The Client Hello message does also indicate all versions of TLS being available.

Comment: It turns out that Comcast is actually the issue. After some digging I found out that comcast is actually blocking my web service. I can use a VPN and it works perfectly. Now the question is how do I get comcast to not block it?

Comment: You should sort this out with Comcast somehow I think.

Answer (score 0):

**What is the *ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR?***

> The *ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR* occurs when the website you’re trying to
> open is facing a problem which is preventing the mandatory exchange of
> certificate.

**What causes this error?**

> This issue can be caused by:
>
> 1. Invalid System Time
> 2. Clear Browsing Data
> 3. Clear Your SSL State
> 4. Disable QUIC Protocol of Chrome
> 5. Check Your Antivirus Settings
> 6. Check Your Firewall
> 7. Disable Extensions

**How to resolve this?**

1. Check the Date of Your System

> When the date of your computer is not in sync with the date of the
> server that you’re trying to access you’ll face the problem of
> *ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR* on your Chrome browser.To fix this, adjust the date of your system to current date and then try opening the site.

2. Clear Browsing Data

> Sometimes browsing data may also come in the way of your internet surfing
> experience, thus giving you that nasty SSL error again and
> again. If the date on your computer is right, follow the steps given
> below to delete browsing data from your Chrome browser:
>
> - Launch Chrome;
> - Press Ctrl + Shift + Delete;
> - Ensure that the time range is set to “All Time”;
> - Check the checkbox for “Cookies and other site data”;
> - Check the checkbox for “Cached images and files”;
> - Hit Clear Data
> - Wait for it to complete, and once it has been done try loading the website again in your browser.

3. Clear Your SSL State

> If your problem still persists, the next thing you should try is clearing the SSL >state of your computer. Follow the steps given below to do that:
>
> - Click on the 3 dots showing next to the address bar in Chrome, right below the close button of the browser.
> - Click Settings and scroll all the way down to Advanced Click on the button to expand Advanced settings;
> - Now scroll down to “Open Proxy Settings” option under System section and click on it;
> - A window named “Internet Properties” will open. Go to Content tab in that window and click on Clear SSL State.

4. Disable QUIC Protocol of Chrome

> Try disabling the QUIC Protocol of Google Chrome browser. To do that,
> paste:
>
> `chrome://flags/#enable-quic`
>
> in the address bar of your Chrome browser and hit Enter; Under
> Experimental QUIC Protocol option, you’ll see that it’s set to
> “Default”. Disable it.

5. Check Your Antivirus Settings

> Sometimes your antivirus may also be the cause behind an SSL error.
> Antivirus programs scan the websites for malicious elements
> and other security threats, which also includes checking the SSL/TLS
> version of a site. If a website is using an outdated version of SSL,
> the antivirus blocks it and doesn’t allow us to visit it. In this
> case, the problem can be solved by disabling the antivirus
> temporarily.

6. Check Your Firewall

> Check your Firewall to ensure that the website you’re trying to visit
> is not present in its blocklist. If you find it there, remove it and
> try loading the website again.

7. Disable Extensions

> Make sure that your website is not blocked by any extension. Disable
> your Chrome extensions one by one and open the error generating
> website again and again as you do that.

If the error still occurs then I would suggest you to open a ticket with [Google Cloud Platform technical support](https://cloud.google.com/support/) in order to investigate this further by inspecting your Project.

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually comcast blocking your connection, I had a similar issue with a cloud run service, it turns out the service for some reason did not had a certificate present or at least when using `https://github.com/drwetter/testssl.sh` it came out empty.  For me, the service was up and running prior and suddenly stop working.  I fixed by recreating the subdomain (cname) record.  I know gcp manages your certificates on cloud run but not sure why it went away, also not sure if there is a way to force a certificate rotate/recreate.